# Cant Turn A TextField String To An Int In textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield

I'm trying to use textFieldShouldReturn to to have my textfield control width of an image when I enter a value but when I try to convert the text in my textField to an Int it shows up as nil in my console.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    let text = textField.text
    let numText = Int(textField.text!)
    if widthPer.text == text {
        print(text!)
        print(widthPer.text!)
        print(numText!) //returns nil
        squareOneWidth.constant = CGFloat(numText!) * 2
        slider.value = Float(numText!)
        calPercentage()
        calPercentageTwo()
    } 
    return true
}
```

I also only allow numbers from 10 to 90 for the user to enter. I think it might have something to do with my function allowing that. How can I solve the problem?

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let num = Double(textField.text!)

    if num! < 10 {
            textField.text = "10%"
    } else if num! > 90 {
            textField.text = "90%"
    } else if num! >= 10 || num! <= 90 {
            textField.text = String(Int(num!)) + "%"
    }
    //print(num!)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because by the time you are trying to convert your `textField` to an `Int` you have already updated its value to a "%" so it returns `nil` because "31%" is not a number.

I'd suggest storing the value of the original number in a `var` so that you can recall it when you need it

```
var originalNumber = 0

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
let num = Double(textField.text!)
originalNumber = Int(textField.text)

if num! < 10 {
        textField.text = "10%"
} else if num! > 90 {
        textField.text = "90%"
} else if num! >= 10 || num! <= 90 {
        textField.text = String(Int(num!)) + "%"
}
//print(num!)
return true
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
textField.resignFirstResponder()
let text = textField.text
let numText = originalNumber
if widthPer.text == text {
    print(text!)
    print(widthPer.text!)
    print(numText!) //returns nil
    squareOneWidth.constant = CGFloat(numText!) * 2
    slider.value = Float(numText!)
    calPercentage()
    calPercentageTwo()
} 
return true
}
```

Comment: I have an issue of being able to type numbers more then 90 and less then 10 but the main issue is resolved.

Comment: If it's over 90 or under 10 it seems to affect the image how can I negate that?